# How do I successfully cast a division equation in a Select statement to a floating point or percentage?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below I create some views in PostgreSQL 9.2. I need to cast the last column in the output below but no matter how I try (e.g. using numeric,real,float) I can't get a floating point or percentage result. Subtraction also does not work. Multiplication and Addition do work.

```sql
Create View Precincts AS Select precinctID,Count(precinctID) As count_prcnt
From voterdb GROUP BY precinctID ORDER BY count_prcnt DESC;

Create View Residences AS Select precinctID,Count(Distinct residenceaddress) As unique_resadd 
From voterdb group by precinctid ORDER BY unique_resadd DESC;
```

```bash
\d Precincts
precinctid  | character varying(80)

count_prcnt | bigint
```

```bash
\d Residences
precinctid    | character varying(80)

unique_resadd | bigint
```

```bash
Select Precincts.precinctid,Residences.unique_resadd,Precincts.count_prcnt, CAST(Residences.precinctID AS FLOAT) / CAST(Precincts.precinctID AS FLOAT) 
from Residences,Precincts Where Precincts.precinctID = Residences.precinctID;

245        |           857 |        1392 |        1
```

```bash
Select Precincts.precinctid,Residences.unique_resadd,Precincts.count_prcnt, (Precincts.precinctID::float8  /  Residences.precinctID::float8) AS PCT 
From Residences,Precincts Where Precincts.precinctID = Residences.precinctID ORDER BY Precincts.precinctid;

101        |           593 |         959 |   1
```

Comment: Maybe you should place your tables with example data here? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12 and post an new link here when you build your schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query below the where condition impose the IDs to be equal so the result of division is **always 1**, result of **subtraction is 0** and finally result of sum is id*2, none of which would be float. However the results will be shown as float like 1.0 and 0.0;

```
Select Precincts.precinctid,Residences.unique_resadd,Precincts.count_prcnt,(Precincts.precinctID::float8 / Residences.precinctID::float8) AS PCT 
From Residences,Precincts 
Where Precincts.precinctID = Residences.precinctID 
ORDER BY Precincts.precinctid;
```

The logic behind the query is not accurate would you please elaborate on what are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I apologize for the logic errors. Thank you Bradia; the query works as expected now: Select Precincts.precinctid,Residences.unique_resadd,Precincts.count_prcnt, CAST(Residences.unique_resadd AS FLOAT) / CAST(Precincts.count_prcnt AS FLOAT)AS PCT
FROM Residences,Precincts Where Precincts.precinctID = Residences.precinctID ORDER BY PCT DESC;

 precinctid | unique_resadd | count_prcnt |        pct

 225        |           683 |         876 | 0.779680365296804
 253        |           847 |        1112 | 0.761690647482014